# How I can convert 10dp in different dimen file

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

What is the value of 10dp in below dimen file.

- sw320dp
- sw480dp
- sw600dp

also provide calculation formula

I will calculate different different way but it not show properly.

Answer (score 0):

use this library for multiple screen resolutions

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
}
```

`10dp` in **sw330dp** would be this

```
<dimen name="_10ssp">11.00sp</dimen>
```

`10dp` in **sw480dp** would be this

```
<dimen name="_10ssp">16.00sp</dimen>
```

`10dp` in **sw600dp** would be this

```
<dimen name="_10ssp">20.00sp</dimen>
```

you can also check your **dp** sizes according to screen sizes [here](https://github.com/intuit/ssp/tree/master/ssp-android/src/main/res)

Read More about [lib](https://github.com/intuit/ssp)